# css3: change font size ratio

Tags: css

i'm just trying out the new font-face feature in css3 for implementing own ttf/otf fonts.
my question: is it possible to change the default font size ratio?
example: i'm using tahoma with 9pt as default font and want to implement ownfont.ttf - the problem: if the browser supports @font-face, the ownfont.ttf with 9pt is much smaller than tahoma with 9pt. is there a way to increase its size ratio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the css3 property [font-size-adjust](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-size-adjust).